# Fastest way to write in HDFS from R (without any package)

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write some data into HDFS using custom R map reduce. I have read process in pretty fast but post processing write take quite long time. I have tried (functions who can write to a file connection)

```
output <- file("stdout", "w")
write.table(base,file=output,sep=",",row.names=F)
writeLines(t(as.matrix(base)), con = output, sep = ",", useBytes = FALSE)
```

However write.table only write partial information (first few rows and last few rows) and writeLines doesn't work. So now I trying:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(base)){
      cat(base[row,]$field1,",",base[row,]$field2,",",base[row,]$field3,",",base[row,]$field4,",",
          base[row,]$field5,",",base[row,]$field6,"\n",sep='')
    }
```

But the writing speed of this very slow. Here is some log about how slow the writing speed is:

> 2016-07-07 08:59:30,557 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/406056
>   2016-07-07 08:59:40,567 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/406422
>   2016-07-07 08:59:50,582 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/406710
>   2016-07-07 09:00:00,947 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/407001
>   2016-07-07 09:00:11,392 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/407316
>   2016-07-07 09:00:21,832 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/407683
>   2016-07-07 09:00:31,883 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/408103
>   2016-07-07 09:00:41,892 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/408536
>   2016-07-07 09:00:51,895 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/408969
>   2016-07-07 09:01:01,903 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/409377
>   2016-07-07 09:01:12,187 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/409782
>   2016-07-07 09:01:22,198 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/410161
>   2016-07-07 09:01:32,293 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/410569
>   2016-07-07 09:01:42,509 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/410989
>   2016-07-07 09:01:52,515 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/411435
>   2016-07-07 09:02:02,525 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/411814
>   2016-07-07 09:02:12,625 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/412196
>   2016-07-07 09:02:22,988 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/412616
>   2016-07-07 09:02:32,991 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/413078
>   2016-07-07 09:02:43,104 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/413508
>   2016-07-07 09:02:53,115 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/413975
>   2016-07-07 09:03:03,122 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/414415
>   2016-07-07 09:03:13,128 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/414835
>   2016-07-07 09:03:23,131 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/415210
>   2016-07-07 09:03:33,143 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/415643
>   2016-07-07 09:03:43,153 INFO [Thread-49]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=921203/416031

So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. I am using data.table.

Comment: Perhaps [`write.hdfs`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rHadoopClient/docs/write.hdfs).

Comment: Probably not code for write.hdfs `write.hdfs <-
  function(data, hdfs.path, hadoop.cmd = "hadoop",sep="\t") {
    tmp.file <- sprintf("tmp_hadoop_%s.csv", as.numeric(Sys.time()))
    write.table(data,file=tmp.file,row.names=F,quote=F,col.names=F,sep=sep)
    cmd <- sprintf("cat %s | %s fs -put - %s", tmp.file, hadoop.cmd, hdfs.path)
    result <- system(command = cmd)
    file.remove(tmp.file)
    result
  }` here `write.table(data,file=tmp.file` writes data into temp file..which consume JVM memory plus writing a intermediate file to load into HDFS later doesnt look like good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my different experimentations with various functions with file writing capabilities I found following the fastest:

```
base <- data.table(apply(base,2,FUN=as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)
x <- sapply(1:nrow(base), 
FUN = function(row) {
cat(base$field1[row],",", base$field2[row], "," ,  base$field3[row], "," , 
base$field4[row], "," , base$field5[row], "," , base$field6[row], "\n" , sep='')
                    }
)
rm(x)
```

where `x` is just there to capture NULL returns which `sapply` throws and `sapply` of `as.character` is to prevent mess up which `cat` does to factors (printing internal factor value than actual value).